# SQL Select From Query

Tags: sql

Doing Revision and cannot work out this past examination question.

Complete the following SQL statement so that it finds the date of the oldest 
painting shown in either exhibition no. E3500 or E5500:

```
SELECT . . . 
 FROM . .
```

These are the Tables

```
Sponsor (sponsor_no, sponsor_name, sponsor_address, telephone_no, . . .) 
Exhibition (exhibition_no, location, curator, . . .) 
Visitor (visitor_no, visitor_name, visitor_address . . .) 
Visit (visit_no, visitor_no, exhibition_no, date, entry-time, exit_time . . .) 
Painting (painting_no, description, date_of_painting, exhibition_no . . .)
```

Comment: Sometimes, not all the tables are needed in the query, as Mureinik's answer shows.

Comment: This isn't likely to be helpful to anyone else, unless they happen to be studying or revising the same (practice) exam(ination) question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MIN(date_of_painting)
FROM   painting
WHERE  exhibition_no IN ('E3500', 'E5500')
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this query,

```
Select MIN(P.date_of_painting) From Painting P Inner Join Exhibition E
On E.exhibition_no = P.exhibition_no 
Where P.exhibition_no = 'E3500' or P.exhibition_no = 'E5500'
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Why bother including `Exhibition`?